# Adding element to xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I have a XML like

```
<SystemSettings version="1">
  <SettingsGroup name="items">
   <Setting name="value1">10</Setting>
  </SettingsGroup>
 <SettingsGroup name="item2">
   <Setting name="value2">1</Setting>
 </SettingsGroup>
</SystemSettings>
```

I want to add

```
<Setting name="value3">5</Setting>
```

in item2 . how do i add that ? Tried using XElement, but could not get it done

Comment: You start by adding sample code to your question - check http://sscce.org for details. (Also reading MSDN on working with XML could be another starting point).

Comment: In addition to what Alexei has mentioned, I would suggest posting your code that you tried with XElement and someone can probably help sort out issues with your code or suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
xdocument
    .Descendants("SettingsGroup")
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "item2")
    .First()
    .Add(new XElement("Setting", new XAttribute("name", "value3"), 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string filename = "test.xml";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(filename);

    XmlElement element = doc.CreateElement("Setting");
    element.SetAttribute("name", "value3");
    element.InnerText = "5";

    doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[1].AppendChild(element);
    doc.Save(filename);
```

Comment: Can we remove hardcoded childNodes[1]? by any chance and search on name="item2" ??